# Which should I use: music band or music group?

Tags: expressions

Which one sounds better? Music group, or music band?

It's a cuban hip-hop group/band, in case the music style matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Musical group.*

If you talk about a band in the context of music,  there is rarely a need to say *music band* or *musical band*. The same can be said for *group*, but at least *musical group* is idiomatic.